# Can we calculate the opponent's hidden values in this statistical battle?

Tags: statistics

## First-order statistical battle

Imagine there is a game in which the user should guess what values the opponent is hiding from the user. In the first battle, the opponent has two hidden values `a` and `b` where `a` is the mean and `b` is the standard deviation (in a normal distribution). The rules of the game are:

- User knows how the generation system works on the opponent's side.
- User does not know what the `a` and `b` values are.
- User can ask the opponent to generate a new value using the values `a` and `b` and show it to the user. The user can ask for a new number infinitely.

### ✅ Solution

In the first battle, the user wins. Because after generating so many numbers, the user eventually finds `a` and `b` or at least gets very close to them.

[image: first order battle]

## Second-order statistical battle

Imagine a new game where the opponent hides four static values `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. The same rules of the previous game apply to this game, but instead of only `a` and `b`, they apply to `c` and `d` as well. In this battle, every time the user asks for a new number, the opponent first generates a new tuple (X=mean, Y=stdDev) where `X` is generated using `a` and `b` (`a` is mean and `b` is stddev) and Y is generated using `c` and `d` (`c` is mean and `d` is the stddev). The opponent then generates a new number using (X, Y) and sends it to the user. Can the user find out what those four values are eventually?

### ❓ Possible solution?

A potential solution that one might propose is to generate K numbers (where K is large enough) and then calculate the mean and stddev of these K numbers, let it be (X1, Y1). Then repeat this step and generate another K number and calculate a new tuple (X2, Y2). We repeat this until we have so many tuples of Xn and Yn. Then we can calculate `a` and `b` using all the Xn, and `c` and `d` using all the Yn.

[image: second order battle]

## Questions of post

1. Does the proposed solution work? Can the user find `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` using this method?
2. If that method doesn't work, can the user figure out what those four values are using any other approach?

Comment: Please provide the source of this method/where you found it.

Comment: @amWhy I mean it's quite natural to come up

Comment: @Avestura I am pretty sure the method will eventually work, it's just how long it takes to get $\epsilon$-close, and are there better methods that are interesting

Comment: You have a positive probability of generating a negative standard deviation $Y$, which is not good news.

Comment: @amWhy I did not find it. I came up with it as a solution that might or might not work.